# Filter in SPARQL query not working when used with MINUS

Tags: filter, sparql

I have a SPARQL query where I want to select all rivers which do not flow through Mississippi or Newyork states. The first one works fine but the second selects all rivers. Can somebody explain why

#### query 1

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

    SELECT  ?y ?k
    WHERE
    {
      ?y owl:flow_through ?k
        MINUS
      {
          {?y owl:flow_through <file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Newyork_state>}
        UNION 
      {?y owl:flow_through <file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Mississippi_state>}
        
      }
```

#### query 2

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?y ?k
WHERE
{
  ?y owl:flow_through ?k
    MINUS
  {
   
   FILTER (?k IN (<file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Newyork_state>,
                  <file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Alaska_state>))  
  }
}
```

Comment: `FILTER` is based on the result of the BGP which is empty in your case inside the `MINUS`. You should use `VALUES` instead to provide inline data, i.e. `VALUES {<file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Newyork_state> <file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Alaska_state>}`

Comment: or even more simple, just remove the `MINUS` and simply use the `FILTER` with a `NOT`: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?y ?k
WHERE
{
  ?y owl:flow_through ?k
   

   FILTER (?k NOT IN (<file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Newyork_state>,<file://c/fakepath/geo.owl#Alaska_state>))  
  
}`